# sed cannot substitute placeholder with env vars

Tags: shell, sed, environment-variables

I'm trying to substitute environment-like placeholders with real env var values, with sed.

What I've tried out so far is this - for eg a given file that has the contents like

```
field=${SOME_VAR}
some-other-field=${SOME_OTHER_VAR}
```

I'd like to replace the content into

```
field=valueOfSomeVar
some-other-field=valueOfSomeOtherVar
```

I'm trying this

```
SOME_VAR=valueOfSomeVar
SOME_OTHER_VAR=valueOfSomeOtherVar

sed -r 's:\$\{(.+)\}:echo "\1":e' file
```

I would expect this to match `${SOME_VAR}`, take `SOME_VAR` with `(.+)` - and then print it out, and print the actual value of the env var with the `echo "\1"` part.

This works to a degree, but I cannot figure out why the above sed returns this error

```
SOME_VAR: not found
```

Is `SOME_VAR` being treated as a command, or is something else wrong?

Comment: Is the full exact literal error message that you are getting? Don't you get `bash: line <number>: fieldecho: command not found`? Does your file has dos line endings? If this is your error message, please post the output of `./yourscript 2>&1 | hexdump`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat input_file
field="${HOSTNAME}"
other_field="${UID}"
```

```
$ sed 's/.*/echo &/e' input_file
field=FDG-PC-NAME
other_field=0
```

To edit the file in place, add the `-i` flag

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/.*/echo &/e' input_file
$ cat input_file
field=FDG-PC-NAME
other_field=0
```

Since a grouping solution has been requested, here is one that gives the same results as above.

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/\([^=]*=\)\(.*\)/echo \1\2/e' input_file
```

Comment: so, is this impossible to achieve without using the `&`? any ideas how to achieve this with capturing groups and substitution?

Comment: @eja Sure, that was my original solution, but as the one provided is easier, I changed it.
I will add it again now.